# Node js is hanging if I start the app using Java process builder

Tags: java, node.js, express, process

I have a node js express app which will have APIs for FTP operations using FTP4 node js library. If I start the application using CMD prompt, it is working peroperly. But if i start the same app using process builder is hanging after some time. When I checked the resource monitor, node js app is not taking much memory (52 MB).
What could be the reason for this kind of behaviour?

I added logs in node js app, no error logs appearing when there's hanging. At the same time resource monitor is showing that node.exe process is running.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.